# Download small files from Azure Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have many small svg files (around 200KB) in Azure Blob Storage and I'm trying to download few hundred at a time. For this I'm using something like that:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
     var stream = fileManager.DownloadFile(file);
})

MemoryStream DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
     var ms = new MemoryStream();
     GetFileReference(fileName).DownloadToStream(ms);
     ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return ms;
}

private static IFile GetFileReference(string fileName)
{
     return Storage.GetContainerReference(ApplicationScope.ConfigManager.GetStorageConnectionString(), 
            ApplicationScope.ConfigManager.GetsContainerName()).GetFileReference(fileName);
};
```

Could you please tell me if this is the best way to access those files, if my main concern here is speed?
Do you suggest to store files in some other Azure data store and why?

Comment: Are you seeing any performance issues with the code you've written? Only concern I have is with `Parallel.ForEach`. You may want to restrict the number of parallel threads you launch. Number of parallel threads should not exceed the number of virtual cores on the machine.

Comment: Hello @GauravMantri and thank you for your reply, in average it takes for 100 images around 15 seconds which is around 10 Mbps if my calculations are correct. So I was wondering if it is possible to speed it up. Maybe there is some configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: Please try the new Azure SDKs and the DownloadToStreamAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadtoasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DownloadToAsync_System_IO_Stream_

Nuget: https://aka.ms/azsdklist

Comment: You can also use the Azure CLI download-batch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  I highly recommend using the async/await pattern and the *Async methods of the new SDKs.

Comment: Are all of the files in the same container?  If not, are they all in the same blob storage account?  If they are in the same container, then you can get the container, then get the blobs in that container, then download them.  We have a couple of different options when it comes to how you access the blobs, so that info will help.

Comment: @FB4 I want to ask again(as Jon Gallant asked before), are these files in the same directory? and which SDK are you using(including version number)?